# How to use Imlib2 in a Cmake project?

Tags: x11, cmake, cpp

I have a Cmake project on arch linux and I need to use Imlib2. However, the cmake cannot find the package (see attached screenshot). Usually, this is resolved by installing the dev version of the library, but I cannot seem to find one on arch linux.

Sorry if this is stupid, but I am new to linux dev. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!

[image: see screenshot]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this was a rule. This was in a virtual machine and the machine does not have internet connectivity yet, and vmtools is malfunctioning, so the screenshot was the faster method for me. I will keep this in mind from now on, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imlib2 does not have a .a file for static linking. Thus, the project must use shared linking.

add to CMakeLists.txt

```
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
```